# How to correctly write a nested xpath for selenium

Tags: r, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use `Rselenium`+`seleniumPipes` to access this zipfile by name: "PUB004_PRE_20220316.zip"

```html
<tr id="l1_VkFMX1BSRV9SUl8yMDIyMDMxMi56aXA" class="elfinder-cwd-file elfinder-ro ui-selectee ui-draggable-handle" title="PUB004_PRE_20220316.zip
Hoy 02:20 PM (4.22 MB)">
  <td class="elfinder-col-name">
   <div class="elfinder-cwd-file-wrapper">
     <span class="elfinder-cwd-icon elfinder-cwd-icon-application elfinder-cwd-icon-zip">.</span>
     <span class="elfinder-perms"></span>
     <span class="elfinder-lock"></span>
     <span class="elfinder-cwd-filename">PUB004_PRE_20220316.zip</span>
   </div>
 </td>
 <td class="elfinder-col-perm">lectura</td>
 <td class="elfinder-col-date">Hoy 02:20 PM</td>
 <td class="elfinder-col-size">4.22 MB</td>
 <td class="elfinder-col-kind">Archivo ZIP</td>
</tr>
```

[Picture of the whole code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNq3E.png)

But cant seem to get the xpath correctly.

Some of my tries:

```r
select_file <- robot$findElement(
  "xpath", "//tr[.//td[.//div[@class='elfinder-cwd-file-wrapper']]]//span[@class='elfinder-cwd-filename']//*[text()='PUB004-PRE-20220316.zip']")
select_file$clickElement()

select_file <- robot$findElement(
  "xpath", "//*[@class='elfinder-cwd-file-wrapper']//*[@class='elfinder-cwd-filename']//*[text()='PUB004-PRE-20220316.zip']")
select_file$clickElement()

select_file <- robot$findElement(
  "xpath", "//*[@class='elfinder-cwd-filename']//*[text()='PUB004-PRE-20220316.zip']")
select_file$clickElement()
```

[This](https://www.enteoperador.org/mer/gestion-comercial/informes-publicos-de-procesos-comerciales/informes-de-procesos-comerciales-todos-los-paises/predespacho-tp/#elf_l1_Lw) is the webpage. I want to download a the zip files.

Note: I need to do it by name because I'm interested in downloading the file programmatically by date (20220316).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you were close enough, instead of *`_`* character it should have been ***`-`*** character and should have been **`PUB004-PRE-20220316.zip`**

---

### Solution

To identify the element you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *xpath* and the *`innerText`*:

  ```
  select_file <- robot$findElement("xpath", "//span[text()='PUB004-PRE-20220316.zip']")
  ```
- Using *xpath* with *class* and the *`innerText`*:

  ```
  select_file <- robot$findElement("xpath", "//span[@class='elfinder-cwd-filename' and text()='PUB004-PRE-20220316.zip']")
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, both of these return: `Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
   Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
   class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
  Further Details: run errorDetails method`.  I added the webpage url in my post it that helps

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to click on `tr` parent element containing the `span` element containing the desired file name in it's text. Right?
But the `tr` element itself contains that string in it's title.
So, why not simply to use this XPath: ?

```
"//tr[contains(@title,'20220316')]"
```

Comment: This looks promising, when I run it, I doesnt give and error, looks like it does find the element, the problem is that the `clickElement()` doesnt seem to actually click something in the page. I added the webpage url in my post it that helps